# AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'items'

Tags: python

I have this piece of code and I am trying to understand it and get the output, but I get the error:

```
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'items'
```

```py
def my_func(A: Set[int], B: List[Dict[int, C]]) -> \
        List[Dict[int, C]]:
    D = []
    for b in B:
        E = dict()
        for a, m in b.items():
            if a in A:
                E[a] = m
        D.append(E)
    return D
```

A is a set :

```py
 A={1,2}
```

and C is a dictionary:

```py
my_dic = {
    1: C(
        X=11.0,
        Y=34.25,
        a=1     
    ),
    2: C(
        X=51.76,
        Y=50.63,
        a=2,
    )
}
```

I call the function

```
X=my_func(A,my_dic)
```

but it gives me error. I also converted the dictionary to the list and it still gives me error but this time: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'items'. Would you please help me to understand the code better and be able to run it?

Comment: Why are you trying to pass a dictionary to a parameter that should be a list of dictionaries?

Comment: `def my_func(A: Set[int], B: List[Dict[int, C]]` This says that `B` should be a list of dictionaries.  But instead you passed just a dictionary.

Comment: That's a code I am trying to figure out and that dictionary is an existing file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You define your func as follows:

```
def my_func(A: Set[int], B: List[Dict[int, C]])
```

You say that B will be a list of dict's. But then you call:

```
X=my_func(A,my_dic)
```

Where you pass in a single dict instead of the list defined before.

However, later in the func, you refer to `.items()`, which is a method callable on a dict, but not on a list or an int. When you pass in a single dict instead of a list of dicts, your code is trying to iterate over the element you passed in. Normally you would iterate over the elements of the list. But since you've passed in a dict, it will iterate over the keys of the dict. But your keys are set as int's, so then the `.items()` call fails.

So you just have to tighten up your call structure.

To quickly comply, you can change:

```
X=my_func(A,my_dic)
```

to:

```
X=my_func(A, [my_dic,])
```

That should help... At least now you'll be passing in a list of dicts, even if it is just a list of length one.

Comment: I thought that B: List[Dict[int, C]] mean I should convert the C dictionary to a list so I used .items() and list(), but it means pass in the list of dictionaries.

Answer (score 0):

Because you passed a dictioanry where you were expecting a list (of dictionaries), `for b in B:` is now looping over the *keys* of that dictionary. Each key is an int, which you call `items` on, leading to the error you're seeing.

Try:

```
X = my_func(A, [my_dic])
```

Note that Python type signatures in this scenario are not being enforced at runtime. You have specified a list of dictionaries with ints as keys, and `C` as the value type. Python will not step you from calling: `my_func(A, 42)` but you will get a runtime error.